# Cannot run migration from Django on Docker to MariaDB installed on host

Tags: sql, django, docker, mariadb

I created a Django project running on Docker, and I successfully connected from the container to the host MariaDB server as an URL `host.docker.internal:3306` with the command `sudo docker run -p 8000:8000 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -d kms1212/jsis:latest`. But due to several problems(I can't remember why I did it), I removed the original database, created a new database, and modified `settings.py`. Then I ran the modified Docker image that is built from Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential python-is-python3 pip mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev

RUN mkdir /usr/local/workdir
WORKDIR /usr/local/workdir

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY jsis .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["bash", "-c", "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py showmigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker jsis.asgi:application"]
```

I dropped and recreated the database and checked that no old constraints and tables were left, but despite my effort, I got some error messages from the container log like this eventually:

```
No changes detected
admin
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [ ] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [ ] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [ ] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [ ] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [ ] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [ ] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [ ] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [ ] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [ ] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
contenttypes
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial
sites
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_domain_unique
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1005, 'Can\'t create table `jsisdb`.`django_admin_log` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/workdir/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/workdir/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 249, in apply_migration
    with self.connection.schema_editor(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 164, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 199, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, 'Can\'t create table `jsisdb`.`django_admin_log` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')
```

(+ Edit)And this is model code:

```
class UserPermissions(models.IntegerChoices):
    USER = 0
    HQ = 1
    TEACHER = 2
    OTHER = 3


class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, visiblename, agreement_status, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')
        if not visiblename:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a visible name')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            visiblename=visiblename,
            agreement_status=agreement_status,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, visiblename, agreement_status, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            visiblename=visiblename,
            agreement_status=agreement_status,
            password=password,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.permission = UserPermissions.OTHER

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
    userid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    visiblename = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    permission = models.IntegerField(default=UserPermissions.USER, choices=UserPermissions.choices)
    agreement_status = models.JSONField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_lastlogin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_blocked_anon = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    block_reason = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'visiblename']

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

So, what can I do about this problem? Should I reset all the MariaDB databases? Or are there some better solutions?

Comment: What do your models look like? The error indicates that there's an issue with a foreign key relationship in the model.

Comment: @EvanOttinger I added in the question!